# $http service how to do stuff before sending XHR

Tags: angularjs

I'm a beginner in the AngularJS space and creating my first app and struck at a point where I need to do some stuff like showing a loader before sending the XHR request and again hide it when response received.

I tried googling for it and found interceptors thing is there in the AngularJS for request and response XHR but doing this will work for every XHR request and I just want to do only in my login controller.

Update : I am looking for some jQuery like beforeSend and ajaxcomplete like callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing fancy needed.

```
$scope.loading = true;
$http.get(...)
.success(function() {
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

Comment: Hmm good trick but I was looking for some jQuery like beforeSend and ajaxcomplete like callbacks.

Comment: It's not a "trick". That's exactly what this code does. Executes `$scope.loading = true;` _before_ sending the request and `$scope.loading = false;` on `success` (which is the equivalent of "ajaxcomplete"). Even if there was a `.before()` method on `$http.get`, wouldn't you still need to set something in `$scope` that you cand bind to in your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle please http://jsfiddle.net/2r88Ljer/4/

```
<div ng-app>
   <div ng-controller="Ctrlr">
      <a href="" ng-click="login()">Login</a>
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="loading"></i>
   </div>

   <div ng-controller="anotherCtrl">
      <a href="" ng-click="fetch()">Get Some Other Data</a>
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="loading"></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

and on your JavaScript add:

```
function Ctrlr($scope,$timeout,$http){
    $scope.loading=false;    
    $scope.login= function(){
    $scope.loading=true;
    $http.get("/echo/json/").success(function() {
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.loading = false;
        },2000);
    });
  }
}

function anotherCtrl($scope,$timeout,$http){
    $scope.loading=false;    
    $scope.fetch = function(){
    $scope.loading=true;
    $http.get("/echo/json/").success(function() {
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.loading = false;
        },1000);
    });
  }
}
```

I ve created a demo on how to show and hide your loading functionality when your request starts and completes and will apply just for the controller you want. I used [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) for the loading icon (for simplicity) but you can use anything you want there (img, gif etc).

Hope it helps